# Implementing a trait on HashMap that uses methods with bounds

Tags: rust

I have the following trait that I want to implement on HashMaps:

```
trait IdAssigner<K, V> {
    // If key has already been seen, returns (id_for_key, false). Otherwise
    // assigns a new id_for_key (starting with 0 and increasing) and returns
    // (id_for_key, true).
    fn assign_id(mut self, key: K) -> (V, bool);
}

impl<K, V> IdAssigner<K, V> for HashMap<K, V> where V: Add<V> {
    fn assign_id(mut self, key: K) -> (V, bool) {
        if self.contains_key(&key) {
            (self[&key], false)
        } else {
            let id = self.len() as V;
            self[&key] = id;
            (id, true)
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler gives various errors about the methods I want to call in the implementation on the HashMap don't exist. I suspect that I need to add the same bounds to my impl statement that exist on those methods. How do I fix this code?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=53b2a0c12a5834da6fb4&version=stable)

Comment: Fully corrected [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c778e02b61a617a3c498&version=stable) (needs an external crate to run, so it can't be run in the playground directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error: no method named `contains_key` found for type

As you can see in the documentation of [`contains_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.contains_key), the `impl` block in which `contains_key` is defined, has the bounds `where K: Eq + Hash, S: HashState`. Adding the bound for K to your where clause will also fix the other `no method` errors and the `cannot index a value of type`std::collections::hash::map::HashMap` error.

After that you get

> error: non-scalar cast: `usize` as `V`

which corresponds to this line:

```
let id = self.len() as V;
```

What you are trying to do here is to cast a `usize` to whatever type `V` is instanciated to. This can't work in general, as `V` might actually be something that is not compatible with a `usize` (e.g. a `Vec` or any other struct). Since what you actually want is a `HashMap` from some key to an id, you can simply remove all the `V` generics and directly set the Value parameter of `HashMap`:

```
trait IdAssigner<K> {
    fn assign_id(mut self, key: K) -> (usize, bool);
}

impl<K> IdAssigner<K> for HashMap<K, usize>
    where K: Eq + Hash,
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to allow V to be any integer type (besides writing a CastFromUsize trait and implementing it manually for all the integer types)?

Comment: shouldn't we have `fn assign_id(&mut self, key: K) -> (usize, bool);` else it may not do anything ....

Comment: @tafia: Either that, or implement the trait on `&mut HashMap<K, usize>` instead.

Comment: @EM: you can use the `num` crate, it has several conversion traits like http://doc.rust-lang.org/num/num/traits/trait.NumCast.html and http://doc.rust-lang.org/num/num/traits/trait.FromPrimitive.html and http://doc.rust-lang.org/num/num/traits/trait.ToPrimitive.html

Comment: @tafia: correct, in real code this would be an issue :)